# C# Deserialize XML to a list of ChildClasses

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, subclass

I have a XML from a 3rd party software that I have to deserialize, but I have the spec of the XML.

At a certain point I have a node that contains a bunch of different Nodes of different types. I have to deserialize this Node (Vehicles) as a list. Each of the child nodes is one subclass of the class Vehicle

```
public List<Vehicle> Vehicles = new List<Vehicles>();
```

the definition of the class is as following

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string Vehicletype { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Drive() { return true; }
}

public class Car:Vehicle
{
    public int NumberOfDoors { get; set; }

    public override bool Drive() { return false; }
}

public class Boat:Vehicle
{
    public int NumberOfSeats { get; set; }
}
```

The definition of the XML looks like this

```
<vehicles>
    <car NumberOfDoors="4" />
    <car NumberOfDoors="3" />
    <boat NumberOfSeats="1024" />
    <boat NumberOfSeats="20" />
    <car NumberOfDoors="5" />
</vehicles>
```

At a certain point I have to loop through them and let them "Drive". I don't have the experience With XMLSchema definitions. Now I am using The vehicleType in a factory and some other things. It's basically becoming a mess.

I would need a suggestion how to let the Serializer do this instead of me. I doubt that I am the first one to have this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have to mark `NumberofSeats` and `NumberOfDoors` with the [`XmlAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to tell `XmlSerializer` that these properties should appear as XML attributes:

```
public class Car : Vehicle
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int NumberOfDoors { get; set; }

    public override bool Drive() { return false; }
}

public class Boat : Vehicle
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int NumberOfSeats { get; set; }
}
```

Next, if `<vehicles>` appears as an XML Node inside some containing [root element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element), you can make your `public List<Vehicle> Vehicles` appear as a member inside the corresponding container class, and apply an [`XmlArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to it to indicate that the list should be serialized in two levels, and [`XmlArrayItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attributes to inform `XmlSerializer` of the possible of vehicles that might be encountered in the list along with the start tag to use for each:

```
public class VehiclesContainer // Your container class
{
    [XmlArray("vehicles")]
    [XmlArrayItem("vehicle", typeof(Vehicle))]
    [XmlArrayItem("car", typeof(Car))]
    [XmlArrayItem("boat", typeof(Boat))]
    public List<Vehicle> Vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
}
```

On the other hand, `<vehicles>` is the root node of the XML document and there is no containing node, you can introduce a root node class containing the list of vehicles, then apply multiple [`XmlElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attributes to indicate that the list should be serialized in one level rather than two along with the start tag to use for each possible vehicle type:

```
[XmlRoot("vehicles")]
public class VehicleList
{
    [XmlElement("vehicle", typeof(Vehicle))]
    [XmlElement("car", typeof(Car))]
    [XmlElement("boat", typeof(Boat))]
    public List<Vehicle> Vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
}
```

Having done this, `XmlSerializer` will automatically deserialize your class hierarchy.

For more information, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).